# Randomly adding classes to a generated <li> only once

Tags: jquery, random, html-lists, duplicates, addclass

I'm appending some `<li>` in a `<div>` with jQuery like this :

```
countBlocs = 60;
for (i = 1; i <= countBlocs; i++)
{
    $('#head #lol').append("<li id='losange"+ i++ +"' class='losange'></li>");
};
```

Which look like this in the html :

```
<section id='head'>
    <article id='head_content'>
        <li id='losange1' class='losange'></li>
        <li id='losange2' class='losange'></li>
        <li id='losange3' class='losange'></li>
        <li id='losange4' class='losange'></li>
        <li id='losange5' class='losange'></li>
        <li id='losange6' class='losange'></li>
        ...
    </article>
</section>
```

And now I'm trying to add randomly classes to each `<li>` in jQuery :

```
countBlocs = 60;
for (i = 1; i <= countBlocs; i++)
{
    var paras = $('#head #head_content li');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
    paras.eq(rand).addClass('logo_white');
};
```

This work well but I need to add more than 1 class but only keep 1 class for each `<li>`

So I dupplicated the code above (which isn't great) with a different class name :

```
countBlocs = 30;
for (i = 1; i <= countBlocs; i++)
{
    var paras = $('#head #head_content li');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
    paras.eq(rand).addClass('logo_white'); 
};
countBlocs = 30;
for (i = 1; i <= countBlocs; i++)
{
    var paras = $('#head #head_content li');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * paras.length);
    paras.eq(rand).addClass('logo_red'); <- Another class name
};

...
```

And now my generated `<li>` look like this :

```
<section id='head'>
    <article id='head_content'>
        <li id='losange1' class='losange logo_red'></li>  <- Ok!
        <li id='losange2' class='losange logo_red'></li> <- Ok!
        <li id='losange3' class='losange logo white logo red'></li> <- WRONG!
        <li id='losange4' class='losange logo white'></li> <- Ok!
        <li id='losange5' class='losange logo red logo white'></li> <- WRONG!
        <li id='losange6' class='losange logo red'></li> <- Ok!
        ...
    </article>
</section>
```

**PROBLEM :**

It adds multiple classes on the same `<li>` and I only want one class randomly added to my `<li>` from several classes already defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the items once, then add a random class for each one:

```
var colors = ["logo_red", "logo_white"];

for (i = 1; i <= countBlocs; i++)
{
    var liItem = $('#losange' + i);
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    liItem.addClass(colors[rand]);
};
```

Comment: I even didn't thought about placing the classes in an Array, shame on me :(

Comment: No shame needed! It's never easy to spot things in your own code. The only way to see it is to put it away for a while or have someone else look at it. The result of this: StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Place all your classes in an array, then use your random on the array to get your class and add it to your li.

```
var classes = ['white', 'red', 'logo_white'];
$('#head #head_content li').each(function() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length);
  $(this).addClass(classes[random]);
}
```

Comment: This will do it for ANY li item on the page. consider adding the parent requirements as the query did in the question asker's code.

Comment: Many thanks for answer but I'll keep the answer of René Wolferink because I need to keep control over the countBlocs var and a foreach doesn't fit my needs

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
 $('#head #head_content li').each(function(n) {
        $(this).addClass(myrandomFunction());
  });
```

and split out a seperate 'myrandomFunction' that will return random classes, once per call.